# How to add a new Row on Angular Flex-box

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

How do you add a new row while looping through your data set.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutWrap *ngIf="blogs; else loading;">
        <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.sm="100" fxFlex.xs="100" class="article_card" *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
            <mat-card class="example-card">
                <img mat-card-image src="{{blog.image_1}}" class="article_image">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <h1 class="article_header">{{blog.title}}</h1>
                    <p class="article_caption">
                        {{blog.caption}}
                    </p>
                    <span class="article_date">{{blog.created}}, </span><span class="article_read_time">{{blog.read_time}} read</span>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The desired layout is 2 cards on Large and Medium view while having 1 card occupy full width for small and extra-small view.

Comment: Have you tried with *ngFor then what happens?

Comment: @PareshGami It stacks all the cards in one row. While the desired layout should be 2 cards in one Row then start a new row with 2 more cards. How can i make that dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i achieved the desired layout:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="15px" fxLayoutAlign=”flex-start” *ngIf="blogs; else loading;">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
            <mat-card fxFlex="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" class="card_item" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
                <img mat-card-image src="{{blog.image_1}}" class="article_image">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <h1 class="article_header">{{blog.title}}</h1>
                    <p class="article_caption">
                        {{blog.caption}}
                    </p>
                    <span class="article_date">{{blog.created}}, </span><span class="article_read_time">{{blog.read_time}} read</span>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

For more info please check on this article: [AG-GRID: THE BEST HTML5 GRID IN THE WORLD](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-flex-layout-flexbox-and-grid-layout-for-angular-component-6e7c24457b63)